# python : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to solve classification problem. I don't know why I'm getting this error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`

**This is the main code**:

```
def generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):       
    while True:
        from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
        to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
        for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
            f=paths[i]
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
     if('P' in f):
                y = np.repeat([[0,1]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            else:
                y =np.repeat([[1,0]],x.shape[0], axis=0) 
            yield(x,y)
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75) ## problem here
                   steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))), 
                   validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),
                   verbose=2,class_weight="balanced",
                  epochs=15, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback])
```

where `generate_arrays_for_training` function return `x` and `y` . `x` is a 2D array of float numbers and `y` is [0,1].

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/thesis2/CNN_dwt2.py", line 437, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user1/thesis2/CNN_dwt2.py", line 316, in main
    history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75), 
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1815, in fit_generator
    return self.fit(
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1049, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1122, in __init__
    dataset = dataset.map(_make_class_weight_map_fn(class_weight))
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1295, in _make_class_weight_map_fn
    class_ids = list(sorted(class_weight.keys()))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: The immediate cause is that `class_weight` is a string, when it should be a `dict`.  But tracing that variable back up through the `keras` code to your function call may take some digging.  Make sure that the inputs to `model.fit_generator` match the documentation in type.

Comment: One of your arguments to `model.fit_generator` is a string. You need to correct that. Unfortunately your [mre] uses data we don't have access to, it will be hard for us to find the problem for you.

Comment: @hpaulj I have traced the code and I found the values returned from `generate_arrays_for_training` not string , `x` is a float 2D matrix and `y` is [[0,1]] . I don't know what is the string value

Comment: @wwii unfortunately i am working on very large dataset I can't provide example. But I have traced the input to `model.fit_generator` and found that it goes to 'generate_arrays_for_training' function and it returned `x` and `y` so the error in the returned values

Comment: @wwii I don't know why I am getting this error

Comment: Where do you get that "balanced" is a valid value for the class_weight parameter?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy my dataset is imbalanced data I just want to balance my dataset. when I try `class_weight=None` I get this error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_19 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, None, None]`

Comment: @Edayildiz I am talking about the API, you are not  using the API correctly, balanced is not a valid value for class_weight

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy ok I understand now. Do you know how to solve this error ??

Answer (score 2):

your issue is caused by `class_weight="balanced"` parameter that you pass to `model.fit()`

according to the [model.fit() reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), this parameter should be a dict:
*Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.*

try `class_weight=None` for testing, it should get rid of the original error. Later provide proper dict as `class_weight` to address imbalanced dataset issue.

Comment: @Rusian But my data is imbalanced. How to make my dataset balanced ?? and solve the error ??

Comment: @Rusian S. I get this error when I try `class_weight=None` . **Error**: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_19 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, None, None]`

Comment: with `class_weight=None` you should get rid of the original error. Later provide proper dict as `class_weight` to address imbalanced dataset issue.

The `layer sequential_19` issue is likely not related.  Look into outputs from the previous layer. Perhaps you need  some reshaping.  If stuck - post your model structure (and summary) here at SO, preferably as a new question.

Comment: @Rusian S. please can you tell me How to balance my dataset?? , I've asked a new question I hope you can help me.

Comment: @Rusian S. I use `model.fit_generator()` and `generate_arrays_for_training` to generate data. I wonder if I can use `class_weight="balanced"` with `model.fit_generator()`. I 've asked a new question I hope you can help me in this problem.

Comment: Have you read the link in my answer? What is not clear there?

Comment: @Rusian S. I don't understand what does `class_weight=None` mean ?? , and if I want to balance my data How I can do that ??